# Restkit - NSArray property is always null

Tags: ios, restkit, foursquare

I'm a beginner with RestKit (I have some iOS experience) and I'm having some problems with my NSArray not being populated with RKMappingResult. It only populates itself in the actual 'block' but if I call to access it in viewDidLoad(), it just prints out null.

Could anyone please advise or provide any tips/links to articles?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my code  -

```
-(void) loadData
{

    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"name":   @"name", @"location.address" : @"address", @"location.city" : @"city"}];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=55.903324,-3.171383&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d18f941735&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&v=20130717", kCLIENTID, kCLIENTSECRET];
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"response.venues" statusCodes:nil];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseUrl];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
        //set the array of venues to be the result of what we got back
        //NSLog(@"%@", [result array]);

        NSArray *venues = [result array];
        self.arrayOfVenues = venues; //self.arrayOfVenues is always null when I call it in the other methods
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
}


- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayOfVenues);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //load the venue data
    self.title = @"Venues";
    [self loadData];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayOfVenues);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `self.arrayOfVenues = [venues copy];`

I think you might be losing the reference to 'venues' when you leave the block and that variable goes away.

Also:

> It only populates itself in the actual 'block' but if I call to access
>   it in viewDidLoad(), it just prints out null.

Bear in mind, this block needs to complete BEFORE you try to access the array. viewDidLoad is definitely going to fire before this block finishes, and so will viewDidAppear.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with the data, but if it's in a table or something, simply put a `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the completion block after the array gets set.

Comment: You sir are a genius! You're right, I'm using it in a table and I needed to reloadData after the block! Thanks Stakenborg!!!

Comment: Copying the array shouldn't be required. It should just be the `reloadData` that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to alloc & init array. like this

```
 NSArray *venues =[[NSArray alloc]init];
 venus=[result array];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. However this did not resolve my problem. The venues array is being set, but 'self.arrayOfVenues' is not being set outside of this method. If I NSLog self.arrayOfVenues inside of the loadData method, it prints out just fine. It doesn't print out in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Thanks!

Comment: Initialising an array and keeping the reference to it ('venues`) and then setting that reference to something else just results in the array you just created getting destroyed. It solves nothing and wastes system resources. And if you aren't using ARC it's also a leak...